# Android RealmMigration issue - Migration not applied and still getting io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I am having a problem with Realm, the application is crashing on startup when I update my new APK.

```
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
    - Property 'TransactionData.retriedOnExpired' has been made required.
```

The `RealmMigration` class has the line when that column is added, if I add breakpoints I can see the code being called successfully. However, still the application crashes after the `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` is called.

So somehow the RealmDatabase is not detecting the migration even though the migration code is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that if the RealmMigration helper is in **Java**,  the **kotlin** Boolean classes must be declared as `boolean.class` instead of `Boolean.class`

If the property was declared as a non-nullable Boolean (kotlin) then Realm will expect the `FieldAttribute.REQUIRED` flag to be set.